# error 404 cannot get api node js and mysql

Tags: http-status-code-404

To try to resolve my problem I replaced
this piece of code

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
        res.json({msg: 'Welcome to your book2life api !', status: 200})
    })
```

by this one

```
app.get('book2lifeapi.book2life.fr/', (req, res, next)=>{
        res.json({msg: 'Welcome to your book2life api !', status: 200})
    })
```

I don't think it's fair because the persists. Can anyone explain to me what I should do? This is the full error that appears:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  book2lifeapi.book2life.fr/:1**

https://www.book2lifeapi.book2life.fr is my url api

Comment: Http 404 error means the requested url was not found on the server. This is more likely to indicate issues with how the web server and web application are configured, than an issue with application code or database. Application code may generate 404 responses, but it would be an explicit piece of code (similar to how you generate the status 200 response in your code). You need to check your webserver's logs to see what urls were requested that resulted in the 404 error message.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an HTTP server out of an Express instance in the following lines.

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
let server = http.createServer(app);
```

You don't need to create an HTTP server if you are using Express; an Express instance is an abstraction over the top of the HTTP module itself. Remove lines 2 and 3 from the code block above.

At the end of your code change 'server' to 'app'. Incidentally the app.listen call is where the Express module creates its own instance of 'http.createServer'.

```
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log('listening port: '+PORT);
})
```

Have a look at the getting started code on the ExpressJS website: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is the code that I tried initially and which shows me cannot get / when I am on cPanel. Locally my api works without problem doing as you said, but when I try to put it online strangely it doesn't work. My database is well connected but it is the server that is not working. I really don't see where the problem could come from.